# Does Dynamo have a master node?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Does Dynamo have a master node that contains metadata about what is stored on any node in the cluster(like Hadoop does), or is this information stored in any of the nodes in the cluster - this means that if the load balancer sends you to a random node ABC123D, that node knows that your data is stored in node G72DS5 so it just forwards your request to that node?

Comment: Just to check: is your question regarding DynamoDB? DynamoDB replicates your data across 3 faciliies and is resilient to failures. Was there a particular concern you had about DynamoDB regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope no master node. Dynamo abstracts how and where the hash keys are stored. I'm not sure how the ring scheme works under the covers. I make some assumptions, but I won't post them here.

All rings in the cluster assume the same responsibility.  There is no master node point of failure with this scheme. You also don't have the ability to scale up/down clusters as they automatically provisioned via increased/decreased throughput capacity.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no master nodes in DynamoDB clusters. One of the key principles of DynamoDB is `symmetry`

From their white paper:

> Symmetry: Every node in Dynamo should have the same set of
> responsibilities as its peers; there should be no distinguished node
> or nodes that take special roles or extra set of responsibilities. In
> our experience, symmetry simplifies the process of system
> provisioning and maintenance.

Also, about routing

> Dynamo can be characterized as a zero-hop DHT, where each node maintains
> enough routing information locally to route a request to the
> appropriate node directly.

See https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf